# Powershell move files but not sub-folders

Tags: powershell

I need to moves all the files from a folder to another but not the sub-folders or anything inside it. 
I have no idea of the name or the extension of the files I'll need to move (and some of them will not have any) so I can't use -Include.
Here is an exemple of the structure of my folder:

- Folder1

  - File1
  - File2
  - Folder2

    - File3
    - File4
- Folder3

I want to move File1 and File2 in Folder3 without moving File3 and File4.

So far, I have something that looks like this:

```
$SouceFolder = "c:\Folder1\*"
$DestinationFolder = "c:\Folder3"

Move-Item -Path $SouceFolder -Destination $DestinationFolder
```

But it's copying the whole folder structure, with all the files.

Thanks.

**Solution:**

```
$SouceFolder = "c:\Folder1"
$DestinationFolder = "c:\Folder3"

Robocopy $SouceFolder $DestinationFolder /mov
```

Note: I removed the \* from the folder1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using -Recurse option like this?

`Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Folder1\*.*" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "c:\Folder3\"`

There is better alternative Robocopy for copying files. With robocopy command you have better control on what is being copied with error codes if it fails.

in your case it would be just a simple code like this.

```
$SouceFolder = "c:\Folder1"
$DestinationFolder = "c:\Folder3"
Robocopy $SouceFolder $DestinationFolder
```

see the [robocopy official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for more option

Comment: This is perfect !  I just added the /mov option to move the files instead of copying them.  Thank your very much !

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

Note I'm **not** appending `\*` to the SourceFolder

```
$SourceFolder      = "c:\Folder1"
$DestinationFolder = "c:\Folder3"

# create the target folder if it does not already exist
if (!(Test-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -File | Move-Item -Destination $DestinationFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-Childitem "FilePath" -Recurse | Where-Object {!($_.PSIscontainer)} | Move-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination "Destination"
```

Comment: I just tried this and it's not working, it's still copying all the files and sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7][1]

```
Move-Item -Path FolderToMove -Destination DestinationFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

move files but not subdirs and their files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path FROMHERE -Attributes  !Directory| move-item -Destination TOHERE
```